# Word. Save as PDF without dialog window

Tags: c#, pdf, ms-word, save-as

If I will do this:

```
doc.SaveAs(fOutName, Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF);
```

Dialog window "save as" open. When SaveFormat isn't PDF - don't open.
How do "save as" PDF without dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out why. This works right:

```
doc.SaveAs(fOutName, Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF);
```

But when

```
doc.Close();
```

Dialog window "save as" open. Do this:

```
doc.Close(false);
```